# Git diff fails on file with underscore in path

Tags: windows, git, filenames, git-bash, git-diff

I'm running Windows 7, and I have the latest version of git (2.7.2.windows.1).  I previously used Windows PowerShell as my terminal for git operations, with no issues.  Recently, I decided to switch to Git Bash, but I'm having one major issue.

My project has a directory (within which are many subdirectories) whose name is simply an underscore.  Whenever I try to run `git diff` on a file within that directory, I get the following error:

`$ git diff _/css/templates/jquery.tag-editor.css
fatal: Invalid object name '_C'.`

As far as I know, an underscore is a perfectly valid character in a file/directory name, and tab completion works fine within that directory, so I know the terminal can "see" inside it.  Additionally, other contributors to the project, all of them running OSX, do not have this problem.  And when I run a simple `git diff`, without specifying any single file, it works fine, and happily includes the diff for any changed files within the underscore directory.  It also works if I `cd` into the underscore directory and run the `git diff` from there, so that the path I pass to it does not include the underscore.

What exactly is happening here to prevent me from running `git diff` on these files?  And where does the "C" come from in the error message when I try to do so?

#### Update

When I run `git checkout -- _/css/templates/jquery.tag-editor.css` to discard the changes to that file, this is the error I see:

`error: pathspec '_C:/Program Files/Git/css/templates/jquery.tag-editor.css' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

`C:\Program Files\Git` is directory of my Git installation.  So apparently part of the path is being interpreted as referring to the Git installation directory?  Again, what is causing this to happen?

Comment: `git diff -- _/css/templates/jquery.tag-editor.css` doesn't error out, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.  It produces no output and just brings the command prompt back up.  I'm a little unclear on the meaning of `--`.  What does this tell us?

Comment: @CarlFink, That `--` is usually a delimiter separating command line options from file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems you are experiencing are based on the [Posix Path conversions of MinGW/Msys2](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion).

- on git-bash try to double a slash: `git diff _//css/templates/jquery.tag-editor.css` or use backslashes (which need to be escaped in git-bash): `git diff _\\css\\templates\\jquery.tag-editor.css` or prepend `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`: `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 git diff _/css/templates/jquery.tag-editor.css`
- on CMD you should use a backslash instead of a slash: `git diff _\css\templates\jquery.tag-editor.css` OR double a slash as for git-bash

in order to prevent the conversion.

Comment: Newer link: https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/